# Why Time(UTC) difference occurs in application running in local to azure?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, azure, azure-sql-database

In my application we storing the created **datetime(In UTC)** in database.This works correctly while running the application in the local machine,Same application run from azure nearly +2 min difference occurs from the local executed app.

**Same issue occurs between Sql server(on-premise) and Azure Sql**

Comment: Because the system time on your local machine and the remote server are different.

Comment: I am facing this issue to critical consequences. 
Encrypted communication is not possible on Azure App Services because the web app clock is so far off.

Answer (score 3):

a "+2 min difference" sounds like it may be due to differences in the system clocks between the two systems.

Your question doesn't specify the source of the **"** created **datetime(in UTC) "**

Is that from a database function, or from your application?

The most likely explanation for the behavior you observe is that system clocks on the two different systems are not synchronized using the same time service.

---

A four-dollar timex watch keeps better time than the hardware clock in a $4000 server. (I'm surprised the drift is only two minutes.) If you want the clocks on the two systems to match, there needs to be a mechanism to keep them synchronized with each other.

**FOLLOWUP**

I believe the answer above addressed the question you asked.

You may have some additional questions. I think the question you may be looking for an answer to might be... "How do I configure multiple Windows servers so the system clocks are synchronized?"

Some suggestions

- Windows Time Service (Does Microsoft provide a mechanism?)
- NTP = Network Time Protocol  (Does Azure support NTP?)
- time.windows.com  (What is the default time source on Azure?)
- once a week - (What is the default frequency ...

etc.

Comment: This is true, but I have to add that having two nodes implies that some time difference will happen and software should be able to deal with it.